# How to create and upload files to amazon-S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, lambda, tmp

I have a C# Lambda function that creates a simple .txt file like this:

```
string file = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "tmp" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "file.txt";
File.Create(file);
```

And then I am trying to upload it to S3

```
TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1));
fileTransferUtility.Upload(file, MyBucketNameInString);
```

But, it is returning this error:

> File createdOne or more errors occurred. (The process cannot access
>   the file '/tmp/file.txt' because it is being used by another
>   process.):  AggregateException

Any solutions please?

Comment: is the file /tmp/file.txt open in a text editor or other program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My simpl solution to Uploading a file to amazon S3

```
private void AddFile(Stream image)
{
    InitializeKey();
    var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
    uploadRequest.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
    uploadRequest.InputStream = image;
    uploadRequest.BucketName = AppConfiguration.AmazonS3FileBucketName;
    uploadRequest.Key = _key;

    using (TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(_client))
    {
        fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);
    }
}
```